# why my visual studio 2013 is slow for c++ code compiling

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compiler-optimization

a c++ project, even if I only change minor code, it will spend a lot on time for compiling like below

[image: compile info]

and I found when I compile, the cl. exe must load a huge of memory by several MB's  speed, anyone have idea for this situation

[image: compile info]
[image: compile info]

[image: compile info]

anyway , the code's result is correct but every time a lot of time is wasted on compiling , hope some one could help me

Comment: about how to reduce the compile dependencies about C++,you can reading Scott Meyers' efftive c++ Item 31,Minimize compilation dependencies between files.

Comment: @MSalters yes, I probably misunderstood the question. Comment deleted.

Answer (score 0):

That's actually not a lot of memory.

Modern C++ compilers assume that developers have decent PC's. Unlike JIT compilers (as in Java JVM's), normal C++ compilers have a very strong bias towards better code generation at the expense of compile-time efficiency.

This is also driven by the fact that PC's are generally a lot cheaper than developers. 8-16 GB of memory is not excessively expensive.